# How to use 'Like' in BQL

Tags: acumatica

How do I format a BQL query to use the 'like' sql functionality.  I want to get all the rows where the first two characters of a particular field match a string variable.

Sql example:

```
Select item, customer, uom from table where uom like 'CA%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Somethng like this :

```
public static class Constants
{

  public class likeCA : Constant<string>
  { 
    public likeCA() : base("CA%") { }
   }
}

public PXSelect<MyTable,Where<MyTable.uom,Like<Constants.likeCA>>> MySelect;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[PXCacheName("Filter")]
[Serializable]
public class ItemFilter : IBqlTable
{
    #region FullDescription
    [PXString(IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Full Description")]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public abstract class fdescription : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region SearchDescrWildcard
    [PXString(IsUnicode = true)]
    public virtual string SearchDescrWildcard
    {
        get
        {
            return SearchWildcardUtils.CreateWildcard(this.Description);
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }
    public abstract class searchDescrWildcard : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
    public class SearchWildcardUtils
    {
        public static bool IsSearchWildcardEmpty(string aSub)
        {
            return aSub == null || aSub == "" || new Regex("^[_\\?]*$").IsMatch(aSub);
        }
        public static string CreateWildcard(string text)
        {
            ISqlDialect sqlDialect = PXDatabase.Provider.SqlDialect;
            if (SearchWildcardUtils.IsSearchWildcardEmpty(text))
            {
                return sqlDialect.WildcardAnything;
            }
            if (text[text.Length - 1] != '?' && text[text.Length - 1] != ' ')
            {
                text = $"?{text}?";
            }
            return Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(text, "[ \\?]+$", sqlDialect.WildcardAnything), "[ \\?]", sqlDialect.WildcardAnything);
        }
    }
} 

 public PXSelect<MyTable, Where<MyTable.description, Like<Current<ItemFilter.searchDescrWildcard>>>> SelectMyTable; // Sql Table select
 cmd.WhereAnd<Where<MyTable.description, Like<Current<ItemFilter.searchDescrWildcard>>>>();// BQL query select
```